# Regex to capture between two characters that matches a word inbetween

Tags: regex

I am trying to find out the best way possible for extracting all the text in between two characters (ignoring line breaks) that matches a word in between the two characters specified.

In the below example, i want to find by the zip **22222** and extract/group its block from **{** till **}** that is {
   "zip":"22222",
   "total":2
}

**Example :**

```
{
   "zip":"11111",
   "total":1
},
{
   "zip":"22222",
   "total":2
},
{
   "zip":"33333",
   "total":3
}
```

**Want to extract/capture/group the block {...} for zip 22222 as below :**

```
{
   "zip":"22222",
   "total":2
}
```

I tried the below, but this is capturing the blocks for all zip codes

```
(?s)(?<={)(.*?)(?=})
```

https://regex101.com/r/0wTDyj/1

Comment: Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/0wTDyj/2) help? I also believe JSON parsing will be a better choice for this case.

Comment: You should really be parsing this with a JSON parser. But... https://regex101.com/r/0wTDyj/3

Comment: Your pattern is not accounting for the zip field and the value and the lookarounds prevent the `{` and `}` being part of the match https://regex101.com/r/3CYHrz/1

Comment: Or, probably `(?m)^{\s*"zip":"22222",(?:\r?\n(?!},?$).*)*\r?\n},?$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/80YTVt/1))

Comment: Is there a way to extract the block from { till } by matching just “22222” instead of matching the entire line “zip”:”22222”...

Answer (score 0):

Below regex worked for me :

(?s)(?={)(?:(?:(?!"zip").)*?"zip"\s*:\s*"22222".*?)(?<=})